# How To create Multicolumn TreeView with header and sorting in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, header, treeview, hierarchical-data

I have created `TreeView` demo in  Visual Studio 2008 C# in WPF, but I want to have a header, and when header is clicked, have it sort data. I want to create a demo like this:

```
header1………….header2……….header3

-parent1…………..parent2………..parent3

…-child1……………-child1………….child1

……child1……………-child1…………child1

-parent2…………..parent2………..parent2

…-child2……………-child2………….child2

……child……………-child2…………child2

parent3…………….parent3………..parent3
```

Please suggest any link or samples code.

Comment: What programming language are you using? And what environment? html/javascript, server side, GUI, Linux, command line, etc...

Comment: I want to create demo in in C# WPF. i am new in this if possible plz help.

Comment: Try to edit your question to state these details, and add the right tags. I can't really help you with WPF, but it will help people find your question.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [sample on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771523.aspx)

And another implementation [on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeListView.aspx)